# Calling java method from unity - field and class name different in error log

Tags: java, android, eclipse, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to call a method in android java class from unity c# script.

I exported my unity project to eclipse and i'm having trouble finding the right method :'(

```
    using (AndroidJavaClass jc = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"))
    {
        using (AndroidJavaObject jo = jc.Get<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity"))
        {
            Debug.Log("CallAndroid"); 

            jo.Call("AnswerToUnity");

        }
    }
```

This is the code from unity c#.
the method `AnswerToUnity` is in the launch activity.

However, in the error log and I see the there are `L` attached to the field name and class name.

This is the error log:

> java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no "Ljava/lang/Object;" field "currentActivity" in class "Lcom/unity/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer;" or its superclassess

I wonder if the letter `L` has any effect in finding java's method.

I'm guessing that the field name is wrong. Where did that 'L' come from? I just can't get the method I wrote, to do what I was expecting.

Is there something that I'm doing wrong? Does anyone see `L` attached in field or class names?

This is my java code:

```
   public class UnityPlayerActivity extends Activity
   {
       protected UnityPlayer mUnityPlayer; // don't change the name of this variable; referenced from native code

       ///some android base methods..

       public static void AnswerToUnity()
       {
           Log.i("OG", "yay");
           UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("MainCamera", "ResultFromAndroid", "What's up, Unity :)" );
       }
   }
```

Comment: Unity and Android communicate with each other via JNI.L means class.Check this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html

Comment: O that's why there were L for fully-qualified-class! Thank you for solving my mystery!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

currentActivity is a static object, using GetStatic:

```
using (AndroidJavaClass jc = new  AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"))
{
    // Here, Change method "Get" to "GetStatic"
    using (AndroidJavaObject jo = jc.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity"))
    {
        Debug.Log("CallAndroid"); 
        // Here, change "Call" to "CallStatic"
        jo.CallStatic("AnswerToUnity");

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to mention that I've used GetStatic method but it's the same.

Comment: I posted my main activity's ' AnswerToUnity ' method

Comment: AnswerToUnity is a static method, using CallStatic.

Comment: I changed it to CallStatic, but now I'm getting ExceptionInInitializerError. UnityEngine.JavaAndroidObject._CallStatic (...) in <filename unknown>:0